# Time complexity of operations on a sorted array of sorted lists

Tags: arrays, time-complexity, heap, theory

I have a sorted array of N elements equally distributed in K lists that is also sorted. What will be the time complexity (in tightest Big-O notation) for:

1. Removing the smallest element.
2. Resorting array after the removal of the smallest element.
3. Removing all N elements

For the first part, I thought the answer is `O(1)` since the smallest element is the first element. But the list that it's a part of need not be the first list and so I am unsure.

For the second part, I am not sure (maybe `O(NK)`?)

For the third part, it has to be `O(N)` since we're going through the entire array but, again, I am unsure

Comment: To be honest, this sounds like a comp sci homework question. That's fine, but you might find better answers on [cs.se](https://cs.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: "*But the list that it's a part of need not be the first list*" - Why not?

Comment: I meant that it can be the first list, but it isn't compulsory for it to be the first list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concrete examples help. Let's say you have three lists (arrays):

```
[7, 11, 15]
[3, 12, 19]
[2, 4, 6]
```

Removing the smallest item requires that you first find it. The individual lists are in order, but the list of lists is not. It will take O(K) time to find the smallest item because you have to do a sequential scan of the list of lists.

Once you've found the smallest item, it will take O(m) time (where m is the size of the list that contains the smallest item) to remove it. The reason is that when you remove the first item from the list, all the other items have to move up. That is:

`[2, 4, 6]` becomes `[_, 4, 6]`, and then you have to move things up to make `[4, 6, _]`. (The `_` signifies null, or whatever sentinel value you use to denote "no value.")

I suppose you could say that removal is O(1), and re-sorting the array afterwards is O(m).

You can remove all the elements in O(N) time, provided you don't care in what order you remove them. If you want to remove all the elements in sorted order, then the complexity is O(n * K), because each time you have to find the smallest element. You can improve that to O(n * log(K)) by implementing a K-way merge, at the cost of O(K) extra memory.

Comment: The example helps a lot!
I understand where I went wrong now

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you mean when you say that the "K lists [are] also sorted".

If the numbers are distributed randomly throughout the K lists, but each of the K lists is itself sorted, then it will take *O(K)* time to look at the head of all the lists to identify the smallest element. However, if the numbers are divided between the K lists such that the K lists *A,B,C,...* can be ordered such that *A0<=AN<=B0<=BN<=C0<=CN...*, then it takes *O(1)* time to find the smallest element because you know it is at the head of the first list.

Removing either the smallest or largest element of the array preserves the existing sorted order, so this takes time *O(1)*.

The time it takes to "remove" all the elements depends on your model of computation. It could take *O(1)* time if removal counts as simply disposing of the whole data structure. However, if each element requires individual clean-up, then it will take *O(N+K)* time: *O(N)* for the cost of accessing each element and *O(K)* for the cost of accessing each of the lists.

Comment: The numbers in the list are sorted i.e., the first element is smaller than the second, the second is smaller than the third etc.

Comment: Removing the smallest element from a list of size m could take O(m) time, because all the other items in the list have to be moved up to fill the empty spot. That's if the list is implemented as an array, or with a backing array. If it's a linked list, then of course removal is O(1).

Comment: @JimMischel: Good catch. Though, if you don't need to maintain an invariant, you can reduce to O(1) by keeping pointers to the vector heads at cost O(K).